# Convert ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 using OSX' .bash_profile

Tags: command-line, osx, character-encoding

When running certain rails scripts in OSX' Terminal, I get warnings such as the following:

```
unable to convert "\xA9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for tmp/cache/assets/CC7/4D0/sprockets%2Fd7d58761510113ba5435f0baba05573b, skipping
```

I've added

```
export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"
```

to my `.bash_profile`, but that did not fix anything. Apparently, these warnings don't matter, but I want to fix them. They're literally hundreds of them and they're a bit annoying.

Comment: That value looks wrongish. Provide the output of `locale -a` to see what encodings are enabled on your system. Assign one of these to `LC_CTYPE`. Also, make sure Terminal is set to run in UTF-8 mode.

Comment: LC_CTYPE can be set to just UTF-8 (which is included in /usr/share/locale but not included by locale -a), but utf-8 in lowercase doesn't work. Terminal should set LANG to something like en_US.UTF-8 by default though.